# imported library not found after npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

Following steps from : https://github.com/appfeel/node-pushnotifications#installation

I've installed package :

```
npm install node-pushnotifications --save
+ node-pushnotifications@1.1.9
updated 1 package and audited 244 packages in 14.663s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Using `import PushNotifications from 'node-pushnotifications';`

returns error :

```
> import PushNotifications from 'node-pushnotifications';
import PushNotifications from 'node-pushnotifications';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm unfamiliar with this method of importing a library. For all others I've used such as express the import is as following :

```
var express = require('express');
```

Have I missed a step ?

How to install and import PushNotifications ?

Comment: Are you using something like babel to support ES6 modules?

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: @UmairSarfraz node -v
v10.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.JS `v10.4.1` does not support ES6 modules. While changing the `import` statement to `require` would work, there are a couple of other options that would also work if you want to keep the `import` syntax.

- Upgrade Node.js to Node.js v12 - With [this](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_code_package_json_code_code_type_code_field) version, you can enable the `import` syntax by adding `"type: "module"` in your `package.json`. You will also have to add a `--experimental-modules` flag while starting the server.
- Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to enable `import` syntax in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `import PushNotifications from 'node-pushnotifications';`

to

var `PushNotifications = require('node-pushnotifications')`

fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

- delete `node-pushnotifications` from `package.json`
- Install by `npm i node-pushnotifications`
- Else, you can use install ny `yarn`